# Code inside setTimeout is not firing in expected order

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

newby newb here...I don't think this specific issue has been addressed before on this site, I've searched and searched but can't find anything that works. I want to display a loading image. I am hiding it before my setTimeout and then showing right at the end of the setTimeout. Everything I've read said this should work but it doesn't. My image appears and then disappears right away before my script is finished running. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
function createHTML(data, listName) {

  var arr = data.d.results;

  $(".save").on("click",function(event){

    // HERE IS WHERE I SHOW MY LOADING IMAGE INITIALLY
    $('.logoImg').show();


    // SET TIMEOUT FUNCTION
    setTimeout(function() {

      $("input.title").each(function(){
        var title = $(this).val() ? $(this).val() : null;    
        var currentUserRequest = GetCurrentUser();

        (function (userData) {
          updateListItem(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'MyList',id,itemProperties,printInfo,logError);

          function printInfo() {
            console.log('Item has been UPDATED!');
          }

          function logError(error){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
          }                
        });
      });

      // THIS IS FIRING BEFORE THE ABOVE EACH STATEMENT
      $('.logoImg').hide();
    }, 0);  
  });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem

Comment: edti: sorry just saw your link. Thanks!

Comment: Hey sumeet...i read through that article and I already have a wrapper function around my setTimeout content, but it still doesn't wait to hide my loading image until everything else in the setTimeout is complete. I can' see where I'm going wrong based on that article. Is there something I am missing? Thanks again for helping a beginner!

Comment: If you can make code simpler it would be easy to tell and provide a solution... to start debugging print if you have right elements or not like console log ($this) inside settimeout see what its referring to..

Comment: @sumeet kumar thanks for your direction. i consoled logged $(this) inside and outside the setTimeout and you are correct, they are different. I've now tried multiple solutions from the article you sent but nothing changes this. Here is some simplified code above. Any ideas? Again, thanks so much for you wisdom:

Comment: just have an simple image and try to do the same logic inside a settimeout and then go from there if you can post it here i might be able to help.. use bind to set the context as per link that might help you as well

Comment: Why  are you defining a whole bunch of functions that are then thrown away again? The whole block `(function (userData) { .... })` does nothing: it gets declared, never called (so the code inside it never actually runs), and then it gets garbage collected.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans that is due to edits made to the original question.

Comment: Then @loadytoad is going to have to edit the question to make sense again.

Answer (score 0):

The callback function passed to `each` will be called for each element that matches the selector.

It looks like you want to call `hide()` only after the callback has been called for all the elements.

To accomplish this, you need to call it after the last callback.

Something like this should works:

```
var titles = $("input.title");
var length = title.length;
titles.each(function(index, element) {
  // Do what you need
  if(index == (length-1)) {
    // We are now on the last one
    $('.logoImg').hide();
  }
});
```